# Different executions with different results using the same Random seed in LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, random

In my Libgdx project (for PC) I am using a Java Random object initialized with a constant seed. I use the Random object to generate a lot of different pseudorandom integers. I am not using multithreading, but the integers are a bit different each time I execute the application.

How can this be possible?

EDIT: What is really strange is that the Random object is called a few times more in some executions and I don't know why, causing the random numbers to be a bit different for each execution.

Comment: Are you making calls to `nextInt()` in the `render()` method?

Comment: No, I am using a different thread. In the render() method of the main thread I do nothing.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question, you originally said you were not using multithreading.

Comment: I also put all the code in the main thread and the results were the same. It was just to make the question easier.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of RNG (Random Number Generator) calls changes depending on frame rate such as using the delta-time (animations, etc) to decide when to pull numbers out of the RNG you will get different results as the frame rate is unlikely to ever be the same between two runs.

Comment: This seems to be what I am getting, but it is strange because the Random I am using is encapsulated in a class which is only used in specific zones of my code. Maybe the Libgdx library is using the Java Random class by its own?

Comment: Unless you're giving Libgdx the instance of the random object you initialized, it shouldn't matter what Libgdx does.

Comment: Is this an oddity of Java?  I use seeded Random() in C# all the time and can always produce the same results based on the seed over instances of Random.Next().  I would be surprised if this wasn't the case in Java since it's a major component of pRNG code.

Comment: @JesseWilliams I don't think this is a Java thing; I've always observed Java's behavior for Random to be the same as you've described for C#.

Comment: Ah, I misread @Stephane's post.  Somehow I read it twice, and both times failed to see the leading "if".

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation for Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html),

> If two instances of `Random` are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers.

This holds true if the instances are made via subsequent executions of the code. If your output is diverging, them somehow you are making more or less calls on different runs - the sequence of numbers generated is still the same, but your effectively sampling differently from the sequence each time. For example, imaging thumbing through a book front to back & looking at the first word on the left page - the order of words is fixed, but if you're skipping pages differently each time, the output you observe will diverge between runs.

@StephaneHockenhull gave a likely source as to why this might be. If some casual inspection into that doesn't pin it down for you then I recommend building a [wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) around Random that increments a counter each time you make a call to get a random number. Dumping the number of calls made at intermediate points of execution will let you zero in on where your runs are diverging. Also, I find it's much easier to add breakpoints to wrapper classes; they can feel like a bit of a hassle, but they rarely take longer to code up than the amount of time wasted by blind trial & error debugging.

Comment: That is what I was really doing since the beginning, and also counted the calls a few hours ago, but I still were not able to see the origin of this bug, which makes me think that perhaps I am doing something strange because of the framework libraries.

Comment: Are you saying that on run A you observe call # n (as counted by the wrapper class) to `nextInt()` to give X & on run B you observe call # n to `nextInt()` to return Y?

Comment: No, the number of "n" calls to nextInt() changes depending on the execution. The nextInt() method always gives me the same result for the same "n" call, but the number of calls vary betwen runs.